# How do you make the output of a `readfile` function into source for conduit?

Tags: haskell, conduit, haskell-pipes

I am opening some .txt file via:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  xxs  <- TIO.readFile pathToFile
  return ()
```

The .txt file is of form

```
str_1 \n str_2 \n ... str_m
```

And I would like to make xxs into a source so that it might look like:

```
sourceList [str_1, str_2, ..., str_m]
```

Does the conduit API provide a way to do it without doing some string manipulation on `xxs` first, thus making it into the form `[str_1, str_2, ..., str_m]`?

Comment: What about using `lines` to break up `xxs` into a list of lines? See  [Breaking into lines and words](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.1/docs/Data-Text.html#g:19)

Comment: That is neat, just to check the list of strings is lazily generated by `lines` right? So the whole list never exists in memory, each line is output and immediately consumed by sourceList, and any downstream conduits ...

Comment: Are you looking only for answers using “conduit” or as the tags imply are you also open to answers using “pipes”?

Comment: If `TIO` refers to Data.Text.Lazy.IO, then yes. If `TIO` refers to Data.Text.IO then `readFile` will read the entire file into memory. In either case `lines` will still construct the list of lines lazily will allows for the possibility that only one line is resident in memory at a time.

Comment: @RowanBlush Open to using pipes, but strongly biased to using conduit. I figured people who used pipes have also used conduit so I was trying to cast a wider net.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `lines` from Data.Conduit.Text: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.0.2/docs/Data-Conduit-Text.html#v:lines

Comment: Why do you want to make it like a list ? Just write your won conduit function to stream it without memory leak: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38864188/1651941

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do you make the output of a `readfile` function into source for conduit?

The source function for reading files already exists in the package [conduit-extra](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-extra) in the form of [sourceFile](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-extra-1.1.13.2/docs/Data-Conduit-Binary.html#v:sourceFile). You can also see various other combinators in that module like `conduitFile`, etc.