# How do you save a file using Conduit?

Tags: haskell, conduit, haskell-pipes

How do you save a file using conduit's library? I looked through conduit's tutorial but can't seem to find anything, here is my use case:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  xxs  <- lines <$> (readFile filePath)
  sourceList xxs =$ pipe $$ saveFile

pipe :: Monad m => Conduit String m String
pipe = undefined
```

So there's two question here:

1. Does it make sense to use `lines` to convert a string into a list of
   strings and then feeding it to `sourceList`?
2. How should I implement the `saveFile` function so that when the strings
   `xxs` are fully processed, I can write it to disk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A small minimal example of what you are trying to do using the `conduit` library:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack
     --resolver lts-6.7
     --install-ghc
     runghc
     --package conduit-extra
     --package resourcet
     --package conduit
 -}

import Data.Conduit.Binary (sinkFile, sourceFile)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Resource
import Data.Conduit (($$), await, Conduit, (=$), yield)
import Data.Monoid ((<>))
import Control.Monad.IO.Class

myConduit = do
  str <- await
  case str of
    Just x -> do
              liftIO $ print "some processing"
              yield x
              myConduit
    Nothing -> return ()


saveFile :: FilePath -> FilePath -> IO ()
saveFile f1 f2 = runResourceT $ sourceFile f1 $$ myConduit =$ sinkFile f2

main :: IO ()                 
main = saveFile "test.txt" "atest.txt"
```

> How should I implement the saveFile function so that when the strings xxs are fully processed, I can write it to disk?

You implement that in your `myConduit` function. Note that in your example you are using `readFile` function call which will read the file lazily. Conduit provides it's own abstraction for reading and writing files, you should use that.